# Best practise for SQL in .NET project

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, web-applications, linq-to-sql

I'm a very beginner in .NET and now I'm developing a little project (web API) using NancyFX framework. In my project, I need to use SQL database for some very basic tasks like storing registered users' details or getting some user information. I'd like to know what is the most popular, convenient and modern way of using SQL in .NET for beginners? I mean, should I use LINQ or just pure SQLClient functionality or are there any good libraries for working with SQL on .NET? I've tried to implement LINQ to SQL pattern but ended up with huge chunks of unused auto generated code and even bigger mess in my head...

Comment: Take a look at the entity frame work code first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a framework to communicate with you're database I would recommend using Entity framework, its very convenient and easy and has the Code first approach which you should read about.
More over i suggest you follow the repository pattern,

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx

This basically means - each object you save in the db, will have a repository which will contain all the object of its kind and that will be you're entry point to reading/inserting/updatibg/and deleting rows from the db, while abstracting away all details of implementation - in our case I recommend entity framework as I mentioned before.

Good luck

Comment: I've read a little bit about the Repository pattern. If I understand it right, this approach is already implemented by the Entity Framework Code First. I think `DbContext` is basically a repository's base class. I have to derive from it and create my own class that will work on objects that represent my SQL database's tables. Am I right? Or do I have to put all the logic of communicating with the databse to separate classes for each entity (table)? I.e., if I have two tables: Clients and Friends, do I have to create a class for each where I put the CRUD logic?

Comment: Hey I am glad you read about it, the dbcontext object represents you're database, like you said you need to derive from it and than specify the DbSet's you need, in you're case - DbSet<Client> and DbSet<Friend>.         You should put the CRUD logic inside a repository class dedicated to each entity in you're dbcontext, I recommend you read this article  -http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/generic-repository-pattern-entity-framework-asp-net-mvc-and-unit-testing-triangle , which explains and  demonstrates the repository pattern in work with entity framework, good luck!